# Is my user interface color contrast good and is there a better way to place the information

Tags: gui-design

As stated in the question, can I get some comments on the way my UI is placed and the color contrast. Appreciate any feedbacks. Thank you.

[image: Monitor]

Comment: This will likely be closed as it's mostly opinion/critique. But to help you alnog, the contrast is OK, but perhaps a bit extreme. As far as layout, it seems quite random. What do the numbers mean on the left? Why are the numbers on the bottom spelled out? What does that mean? What is series 1? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have yet to setup the chart thus placed random information there. I was more concerned with the color contrast plus how the UI is placed such as should the chart go right, top and so on.

Comment: You can also check your contrast on [Color Contrast Checker](http://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/). If that tool says that is OK, then it's perfect from the accessibility point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contrast is makes the readable on the black background. You can lessen the brightness and saturation a bit.  Also, the aqua text on the white background (in your chart's legend) is hard to read.

I see that you are using text boxes to display values. This might lead the user to think they can edit those values, though I think those values are read-only. Consider a label instead.

With regard to those four values, you might want to consider laying them out in a 2-column table with the label on the left column (right-aligned, bolded) and the values on the right column (left-aligned).

For displaying double/float values, limit the number of decimal places to 2.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that I think ten, twenty, fifty, thirty , fourty is not in the correct order.